# SPARQL execdescribe query in jena only giving prefix as output

Tags: sparql, jena

Below SPARQL execdescribe query giving me only two prefixes as output while running with Jena query but when I run this query on virtuoso SPARQL endpoint it's giving perfect output.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre
WHERE { 
?movie rdf:type db:Film ;
prop:author ?author ;
prop:genre ?genre .
}
LIMIT 2
OFFSET 0
```

When I run with Jena I am getting only two line output like this,

```
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
```

Below is my code which I am using but with some query its working fine,

```
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" + 
                "PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> " + 
                "PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>" + 
                "DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre" + 
                "WHERE { " + 
                "?movie rdf:type db:Film ;" + 
                "prop:author ?author ;" + 
                "prop:genre ?genre ." + 
                "}" + 
                "LIMIT 2" + 
                "OFFSET 0";

        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://localhost:8890/sparql", queryString);
        Model results = qexec.execDescribe();

        results.write(System.out,"TTL");
```

Its perfectly giving me output on virtuoso SPARQL end point.
below is screen shot,
[image: SPARQL]

Comment: Prefixes do not belong to the content and are just for rendering. Clearly, Jena and Virtuoso do have different predefined prefixes that will be used for rendering. In Jena you must add the prefixes that you want to have, as usual everything is in the [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Prefixes)

Comment: Hi @AKSW maybe you don't understand my question properly actually I don't ask for a prefix.I am asking I am only getting prefix as output not other like as shown in the screenshot.As per your document link i am not asking that bdw.

Comment: Ok, sorry. But maybe for the future, try first to compare both query strings... Clearly, in your Java code, there is a missing space between `"DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genre"` and the next line `WHERE ...` which results in a string `DESCRIBE ?movie ?author ?genreWHERE`

Comment: @AKSW thank you very much you saved my lot of time. you are right it's a space issue I just edited java query code. now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments by @AKSW, There is a space issue in the query. So after edited my query, it will perfectly work fine.